# AWS and Cognito

Tags: oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I'm a newbie to this stuff so downloaded the samples which is all fine and I thought I could see what was going on and what I needed to do. However, got a bit stuck for no obvious reason so I wondered if anyone could maybe give me some hints.

I'm trying to engineer Cognito authentication and identity into an old Apache Struts 1 legacy web application written in Java, so all the activity needs to be server-side. Using the Cognito https://xxx.auth.xxx.amazoncognito.com/login? URL I can successfully authenticate and get an auth code back using this URL providing my client id, redirect URI and response_type=code so all good thus far.

If I then create an HttpClient (as per the sample code in Github) and call the token URL https://xxx.auth.xxx.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token and write various parameters to the request body (grant_type=authorization_code, client_id=as previously, redirect_uri=my URI and code=auth code just returned), I get an "unauthorized_client" message returned. But the code is valid albeit for authorization, and the client_id is correct because I used it previously.

My log:

```
Cognito following successful signin, continuing to url http:[redacted]/passport/CognitoHandlerSignIn.do?code=62eeb0b1-a76b-489b-bd28-e42023a497bd
```

(this was the /login succeeding)

```
Callback from Cognito received
```

(following is the log dump of the /oauth2/token URI called to)

```
Cognito token signin URL is https:[redacted].amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token  
HTTP request header, added Authorization=Basic M29wcGR0azdpYzF2YjloNGd0OTQzNXYxcmI6MW9mMmFsaWNzZGR2dHZ1NmFkOHRuc2s4cnJ0cXEyYm0yc3RqbG1mcmkyamhkdXBubG1wMw==  
HTTP request header, added Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded  
HTTP request body, added grant_type=authorization_code  
HTTP request body, added  
 redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F<redacted>%2Fpassport%2FCognitoHandlerSignIn.do
HTTP request body, added code=62eeb0b1-a76b-489b-bd28-e42023a497bd  
HTTP request body, added client_id=[redacted]  
HTTP request is sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https: 
 [redacted].auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token  
HTTP Json result=<{"error":"unauthorized_client"}>  
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject not found.  
at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:454)  
at
```

What's wrong with this picture? I tried also adding client_id, code as URL parameters but I just get an "invalid_client" message instead.

I also tried using the /oauth2/token URI directly from the Struts app to provide a token but it returns the id_token using # rather than ? in the parameter list so it is client-side only and hence can't be intercepted by the Struts app and so will be a pain to forward to the server, but I could write some Javascript to do it if I had to. It doesn't seem the path of least resistance, though, as it seems wrong that the pure Java server side call doesn't work so I must be doing something wrong which isn't obvious to me.

Comment: Does your client have a _secret_key_ ? In that case, you would need to do Basic authentication for the URI with _client_id:client_secret_.